# PHP function to return array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to fix a third party wordpress plugin that my company had commissioned before I joined and now the third party company is nonresponsive/unwilling to help. I have a form on the WP site that takes information from a drop down menu and then uses it to calculate which product the customer needs based on certain parameters. I have calculate function that is supposed to take a variable, get array info based on that variable, and then give a calculation from that information:

```
function calculation($d){
    
    //$wind = pW($d['windSpeed']);
    
    $pad_data = anchor($d['site']);
    
    //if($d['site'] == "concrete"){
        $da = [];
        foreach($pad_data as $key => $value){
            foreach($value as $k => $v){
                if($d['site'] == "ground" && strpos($k,"concrete") !== false){
                    continue;
                }elseif($d['site'] == "concrete" && strpos($k,"ground") !== false){
                    continue;
                }
                $foi = foi($v,$d);
                if($foi > 1){
                    if($k == "noanchor"){
                        $de[] = $key." Pad with ".$v['nanchor']." anchor";    
                    }else{
                        $de[] = $key." Pad with ".$v['nanchor']." ".$k." anchor";    
                    }
                    
                    //print_r($d);
                    
                    return json_encode($de);
                }
            }
        }
        
    //}
    
    //print_r($da);
    // foreach($da as $r =>){
    //     if($r)
    // }
    
}
```

However it always returns the same reply. the anchor function looks like the following:

```
function anchor(){
    
    $array[36] = [
                    "noanchor" => [
                                        "lpad" => 36,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 162,
                                        "wanchor" => 205,
                                        "nanchor" => 0,
                                        "apw" => 162
                                    ],
                    "ground_1"  =>  [
                                        "lpad" => 36,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 162,
                                        "wanchor" => 205,
                                        "nanchor" => 2,
                                        "apw" => 572
                                    ],
                    "ground_2"  =>  [
                                        "lpad" => 36,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 162,
                                        "wanchor" => 205,
                                        "nanchor" => 4,
                                        "apw" => 982
                                    ],
                    "concrete"  =>  [
                                        "lpad" => 36,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 162,
                                        "wanchor" => 232,
                                        "nanchor" => 4,
                                        "apw" => 1092.4
                                    ]                
                ];
                
    $array[40] = [
                    "noanchor" => [
                                        "lpad" => 40,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 200,
                                        "wanchor" => 205,
                                        "nanchor" => 0,
                                        "apw" => 200
                                    ],
                    "ground_1"  =>  [
                                        "lpad" => 40,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 200,
                                        "wanchor" => 205,
                                        "nanchor" => 2,
                                        "apw" => 610
                                    ],
                    "ground_2"  =>  [
                                        "lpad" => 40,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 200,
                                        "wanchor" => 205,
                                        "nanchor" => 4,
                                        "apw" => 1020
                                    ],
                    "concrete"  =>  [
                                        "lpad" => 40,
                                        "hpad" => 4,
                                        "wpad" => 200,
                                        "wanchor" => 232,
                                        "nanchor" => 4,
                                        "apw" => 1130
                                    ]                
                ];
                
    return $array;
    
}
```

and when I input `var_dump(anchor());` or `print_r(anchor());` it always give the same reply regardless of what arguments I pass. These functions:

```
var_dump(anchor($array[40]));
var_dump(anchor([36],['noanchor']));
```

both give the same reply:

```
array (size=2)
  36 => 
    array (size=4)
      'noanchor' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 36
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 162
          'wanchor' => int 205
          'nanchor' => int 0
          'apw' => int 162
      'ground_1' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 36
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 162
          'wanchor' => int 205
          'nanchor' => int 2
          'apw' => int 572
      'ground_2' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 36
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 162
          'wanchor' => int 205
          'nanchor' => int 4
          'apw' => int 982
      'concrete' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 36
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 162
          'wanchor' => int 232
          'nanchor' => int 4
          'apw' => float 1092.4
  40 => 
    array (size=4)
      'noanchor' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 40
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 200
          'wanchor' => int 205
          'nanchor' => int 0
          'apw' => int 200
      'ground_1' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 40
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 200
          'wanchor' => int 205
          'nanchor' => int 2
          'apw' => int 610
      'ground_2' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 40
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 200
          'wanchor' => int 205
          'nanchor' => int 4
          'apw' => int 1020
      'concrete' => 
        array (size=6)
          'lpad' => int 40
          'hpad' => int 4
          'wpad' => int 200
          'wanchor' => int 232
          'nanchor' => int 4
          'apw' => int 1130
```

and `print_r(anchor([36],["noanchor"]));` and `print_r(anchor(40));`

both give same output:

```
Array ( [36] => Array ( [noanchor] => Array ( [lpad] => 36 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 162 [wanchor] => 205 [nanchor] => 0 [apw] => 162 ) [ground_1] => Array ( [lpad] => 36 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 162 [wanchor] => 205 [nanchor] => 2 [apw] => 572 ) [ground_2] => Array ( [lpad] => 36 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 162 [wanchor] => 205 [nanchor] => 4 [apw] => 982 ) [concrete] => Array ( [lpad] => 36 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 162 [wanchor] => 232 [nanchor] => 4 [apw] => 1092.4 ) ) [40] => Array ( [noanchor] => Array ( [lpad] => 40 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 200 [wanchor] => 205 [nanchor] => 0 [apw] => 200 ) [ground_1] => Array ( [lpad] => 40 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 200 [wanchor] => 205 [nanchor] => 2 [apw] => 610 ) [ground_2] => Array ( [lpad] => 40 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 200 [wanchor] => 205 [nanchor] => 4 [apw] => 1020 ) [concrete] => Array ( [lpad] => 40 [hpad] => 4 [wpad] => 200 [wanchor] => 232 [nanchor] => 4 [apw] => 1130 ) ) )
```

Perhaps this is not the issue overall but it seems like I can't get another response from anchor(). I have searched voraciously for php functions that are arrays like the above and I can't find anything. I know that if the array where set up just $array[36] = [all the info] that I could retrieve it by doing print_r($array[36]) and even specify individual parts of the nested arrays. But this plugin did work at some point so I'm trying to not have to start from square one. I am 100% confident that the steps of the code work up to the point of sending data to the calculate function but I don't know where the issue comes after that point. I can provide more code if needed or more of the overall picture but the main question I have is how do I get the desired output of $pad_data = anchor($d['site']) to actually get the desired information from the array. $d is the data being passed and 'site' is one of the array items in the data. The data array prints as:

```
Array(
[windSpeed] => 140
[manufacturer] => Rheem
[series] => RP20
[Nominal_Capacity] => 5.0
[modelNumber] => RP2060
[weight] => 355
[lenght] => 35.7500
[width] => 35.7500
[height] => 51.0000
[site] => concrete
)
```

and yes I know length is misspelled, but whoever wrote it originally wrote it wrong every instance and I've just not changed that yet.

Any guidance is extremely welcome!

Comment: Ok. I may be wrong. But in the PHP code, you are declaring `$da = [];` and you are pushing to the array `$de` as in `$de[] = $key." Pad with ".$v['nanchor']." anchor";`. Is that part of the logic ?

Comment: The anchor function does not take any arguments. When you call it, you are supplying arguments. It is apparent that what you think the anchor function does and what it really does are two very different things.

Comment: You have written your `anchor` function to always return the same result (there are no conditional structures in there), so even if you did define an argument for it to take, I don't see how you can expect it to return a different result based on it. You would need to actually write some logic that uses the argument in order for it to do what you expect.

Comment: Adding to the other comments, `anchor()` needs to receive a parameter and then have logic to decide what to do with that parameter so the correct value that you want/expect will be returned.

Comment: There appears to be some confusion based on the comments saying that I wrote this incorrectly or I have set up function wrong: as stated I am trying to fix something a third party has completed that I don't have a great grasp on. Unfortunately this leaves me unable to answer questions like is $da = [] part o the logic. I was told this code used to work. I appreciate the comments on the logic needed, any actual advice on that would be great. Is the way to go about this to add arguments to the anchor function and then in the top of the function before going to the array evaluate that argument?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in the code they have just set the variable equal to an array, and then tried to access that variable as if it contained some internal logic. You can just use $pad_data as an array variable and you don't need to pass any arguments to the anchor "function". Overall this was a small issue in the functionality of the app but this is the answer to this part of my question.